# Eclipse error when using Scanner to read a Float

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

As part of a training exercise I'm coding a project to simulate a vending machine, and when I take in a float value Eclipse throws the following errors:

The error in question occurs in this block of code:

```
public void Restock() {
            boolean done = false;
            Float price;
            String quit, name;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            scan.useLocale(Locale.US);
            scan.useDelimiter("\\n");

            while (!done) {
                System.out.println("Enter Item Name: ");
                name = scan.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Price (XX.XX): $");
                price = scan.nextFloat();
                item = new Items(name, price);
                stock.add(item);
                System.out.println("Quit? (Y/N): ");
                quit = scan.next();
                while (!quit.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !quit.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Quit? (Y/N): ");
                    quit = scan.next();
                }
                if (quit.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                    done = true;
                } else if (quit.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                    done = false;
                }
            }
            scan.close();
        }
```

I've tried running the code without the delimiter, adding an additional 'scan.nextLine();' statement above 'price = scan.nextFloat();' and in that case on the second pass through the loop it skipped asking for the name and went right to the price. Can somebody help me figure this out?

Comment: Can u tell us what error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your question skips over a *lot* of information on how the class and everything else works, a possible source of your errors is that you are using a `Float` to store your value, but using `nextFloat()` to get your value, which returns a `float`. Shouldn't be an issue, but you never know. Regardless, a solution you may try (which is how it always works for me) in that instance is to replace `scan.nextFloat()` with `Float.valueOf(scan.next())` so you don't have to depend on finicky autoboxing at all.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Moving forward, what kind of information should I include in my questions? I didn't want to include code or details that weren't related to solving the problem at hand.

Comment: @Lotus if it worked, great! Please mark the answer that worked for you by clicking the green "check" mark so others know which answer solved your problem if they find themselves coming to your question because they have a similar problem. As for improving questions, generally a stack trace of the error or expected input/output versus real input/output is helpful, as well as comments of what each part of the code is supposed to do or descriptions/source of what custom classes/methods do when they are involved in the part in question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not provide a lot of information. However, here's my quickest attempt at recreating your code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RestockDemo {
    public ArrayList<Items> stock = new ArrayList<Items>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestockDemo restockDemo = new RestockDemo();
        restockDemo.restock();
    }

    public void restock() {
        boolean done = false;
        float price;
        String quit, name;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        scan.useLocale(Locale.US);
        scan.useDelimiter("\\n");

        while (!done) {
            System.out.print("Enter Item Name: ");
            name = scan.next();
            System.out.print("Enter Price (XX.XX): $");
            price = scan.nextFloat();

            Items item = new Items(name, price);
            stock.add(item);
            System.out.println(stock.get(0).name);
            System.out.println(stock.get(0).price);

            System.out.print("Quit? (Y/N): ");
            quit = scan.next();
            while (!quit.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !quit.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                System.out.print("Invalid Entry. Quit? (Y/N): ");
                quit = scan.next();
            }
            if (quit.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                done = true;
            } else if (quit.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                done = false;
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }

    class Items {
        public String name;
        public double price;
        Items(String name, double price) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried [Bakna's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57997081/11417454) in Eclipse and it worked of course. Accepting a string instead and parsing it as a float is probably a nice quick fix.

Nevertheless, the weird thing I experienced when experimenting with your code was that when I ran the code above with the original *scan.nextFloat* implementation on NetBeans, it worked. On the other hand, a java.util.InputMismatchException occurs when I try the code in Eclipse.

Here are the different outputs:

**NetBeans:**

```
run:
Enter Item Name: Lilly Pulitzer Pearl Romper
Enter Price (XX.XX): $198.88
Lilly Pulitzer Pearl Romper
198.8800048828125
Quit? (Y/N): y
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 minutes 0 seconds)
```

**Eclipse:**

```
Enter Item Name: Lilly Pulitzer Pearl Romper
Enter Price (XX.XX): $198.89
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Unknown Source)
    at RestockDemo.restock(RestockDemo.java:26)
    at RestockDemo.main(RestockDemo.java:11)
```

Frankly, I'm surprised to find that two different development environments can produce inconsistent results and I'm curious to find out why. I am assuming it has something to do the new line delimiter, but I'm not sure.

Comment: According to your posted source, you used a primitive float, unlike the Float class that OP used.

Comment: Interestingly, the results I shared are still the same irrespective of whether I use the primitive float or the wrapper Float class: works fine in NetBeans, throws an InputMismatchException in Eclipse. I'm still wondering why this is the case.

Comment: Open another question? Could be different compiler settings. Either way, I avoid autoboxing when I can.